# Jenkins ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "32-bit\*.*, 64-bit\*.*". Configuration error?

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, artifact-deployer

I have few Jenkins jobs running and producing two artifacts with wildcard pattern "32-bit*.*, 64-bit*.*".But one of the job is showing an error while running the build.
 ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "32-bit*.*, 64-bit*.*". Configuration error?
ERROR: ‘32-bit*.*’ doesn’t match anything: even ‘32-bit’ doesn’t exist

I have other jobs which has the same configuration which is producing the artifacts. I am using MSBUILD to build the artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2010 licence was expired. Add the licence and all set.